# Is it correct to use Present Prefect with "past week"?

Tags: present-perfect

I am having hard time judging if the use of present perfect is correct in the following question: **"How many times have you done these things in the past week?"**

According "Practical English Usage", we cannot use present prefect with finished-time words such as "yesterday, last week, three years, ...etc". Is the "past week" a finished-time expression?

Please, help me get to the bottom of this.

Comment: The question is: does "the past week" end now, or did "the past week" end earlier?

Comment: I can't tell either, because this question preface an activity in a lesson about "present prefect". I took it from an English book.

Comment: Often in English, "the past week" ends "now". But I don't think it always does. It would depend on the context.

Comment: Does "the past week" has the same meaning as "last week" in this context?

Comment: No, "the past week" is the previous seven days (which may end yesterday, and may end now). "Last week" is the last calendar week (probably going from Sunday to Saturday, but maybe a workweek going from Monday to Friday). Although I should add that different English speakers may have different interpretations of these.

Comment: How would you rephrase the question? (avoid all confusion or context dependence and still use present perfect)

Comment: Since the phrase "the past week" certainly ***can*** end now, the use of "have you done" is correct. (It wouldn't be with "last week".)

Comment: Past references the week that just ended.  It is the opposite of next week.  It is different from last week.  I don't understand how anyone can question using the present perfect.

Comment: @PeterShor You said "the past week"is the previous seven days which may end yesterday, and may end now. Can I say: or it is about to end. maybe tomorrow, maybe the day after tomorrow? You know what I mean? I mean maybe for some reason tomorrow doesn't count, considering.